# Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Could not get document from window handle (NoSuchDriver)

Tags: c#, selenium, internet-explorer-10, ui-automation

I tried the code below a 100 times and still get this error:

> Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Could not get document from window handle (NoSuchDriver)

Not much on this error except the Protected Zone sync which is worthless.

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(
    pathContainingIEDriverServer, options);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

IWebElement searchTermTB = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
searchTermTB.SendKeys("jimmy collins blog");

IWebElement searchBtn = driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnG"));
searchBtn.Click();

driver.Close();
```

Comment: Well have you set your protected mode settings *correctly*? *Correctly* means *not* using the instability setting you've got there and physically set the required settings on the machine: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration

Comment: You haven't specified what version of IE you're using, so I'm going to use my psychic debugging powers to guess you're using IE10 on Windows 8, or IE11. If it's the former, try turning off Enhanced Protected Mode in Internet Options. If it's the latter, you're hitting [bug 6511](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6511) in the Selenium issue tracker. As noted there, there is no solution or workaround; the issue is a bug caused by Microsoft, and it is incumbent on them to provide a fix or workaround.

Comment: IE 11. I'm at a dead end it sounds like.

Comment: Turns out the webBrowser control in WinForms had every I need after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the webBrowser control in WinForms had every I need after all